# Sort products by producer name otherwise by something else in a "Rails way"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My customer wants to order products by `producer name` if producer name is `"ABC"`, otherwise order the result by `parameters_count` and `images_count`. My schema looks like this:

```
Parts

id int PK

producer_id int

images_count int

parameters_count int
```

```
Producers

id int PK

lauber_id String

name string
```

The result of the sorting should be that the products that have a producer of ABC should be on the list first, otherwise show the products that have images count and parameters count greater than 0.

What would be the best way of sorting the results in a "Rails way". So far I have this.

```
Part.joins('join producers on parts.producer_id = CAST(producers.lauber_id as INT)')
  .order("CASE WHEN producers.name = 'ABC' then producers.name END, images_count, parameters_count desc")
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: I am using Postgres

Answer (score 1):

You can't order some rows on different numbers of columns.  You want to order on 3 things, the first of which is a boolean.  And since "false" come before "true", you need to reverse the order:

```
producers.name = 'ABC' desc, images_count, parameters_count desc
```